# CreateProcess with CREATE_SUSPENDED cannot be ResumeThread-ed

Tags: vba, winapi, createprocess

I'm stuck using WINAPI's CreateProcess with CREATE_SUSPENDED and ResumeThread from VBA.

I would like to start a process (and receive it's Process ID) and be able to suspend and resume its main thread (depending on a more complicated scheme considering the resource utilisation use of my computer - not detailed here). I came up with the below code and have the following problems:

1. LastDllError is 18 after calling CreateProcess although the return
   value is nonzero. What does this mean?
2. ResumeThread fails with ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE, and does not resume
   it. What is wrong here?

My code:

```
Option Explicit


Private Type SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    nLength              As Long
    lpSecurityDescriptor As Long
    bInheritHandle       As Long
End Type

Private Type STARTUPINFO
    cb              As Long
    lpReserved      As String
    lpDesktop       As String
    lpTitle         As String
    dwX             As Long
    dwY             As Long
    dwXSize         As Long
    dwYSize         As Long
    dwXCountChars   As Long
    dwYCountChars   As Long
    dwFillAttribute As Long
    dwFlags         As Long
    wShowWindow     As Integer
    cbReserved2     As Integer
    lpReserved2     As Byte
    hStdInput       As Long
    hStdOutput      As Long
    hStdError       As Long
End Type

Private Type PROCESS_INFORMATION
    hProcess    As Long
    hThread     As Long
    dwProcessId As Long
    dwThreadId  As Long
End Type

Private Const CREATE_SUSPENDED As Long = 4

Private Declare Function CreateProcess Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateProcessA" ( _
       ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
       ByVal lpCommandLine As String, _
       ByRef lpProcessAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, _
       ByRef lpThreadAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, _
       ByVal bInheritHandles As Long, _
       ByVal dwCreationFlags As Long, _
       ByRef lpEnvironment As Any, _
       ByVal lpCurrentDirectory As String, _
       ByRef lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO, _
       ByRef lpProcessInformation As PROCESS_INFORMATION) As Long

Private Declare Function SuspendThread Lib "kernel32" (hThread As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function ResumeThread Lib "kernel32" (hThread As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function DebugActiveProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function DebugActiveProcessStop Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long

Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)


Public Function WinApi_CreateProcess(strCommandLine As String, Optional strCurrentDirectory As String = vbNullString) As Long
    If strCurrentDirectory = vbNullString Then
        strCurrentDirectory = ThisWorkbook.Path
    End If
    Dim sap As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES: sap.nLength = Len(sap)
    Dim sat As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES: sat.nLength = Len(sat)
    Dim si As STARTUPINFO: si.cb = Len(si)
    Dim pi As PROCESS_INFORMATION
    Debug.Print Err.LastDllError ' 0 => ERROR_SUCCESS
    Dim dwResult As Long: dwResult = CreateProcess(vbNullString, strCommandLine, sap, sat, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED, 0, strCurrentDirectory, si, pi)
    Debug.Print Err.LastDllError ' 18 => ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES (but dwResult <> 0 => Success)
    If dwResult = 0 Then
        WinApi_CreateProcess = 0: Exit Function
    End If
    CloseHandle pi.hProcess
    Debug.Print Err.LastDllError ' 0 => ERROR_SUCCESS
    Dim dwSuspendCount As Long: dwSuspendCount = ResumeThread(pi.hThread)
    Debug.Print dwSuspendCount ' -1
    If dwSuspendCount = -1 Then
        Debug.Print Err.LastDllError ' 6 => ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE
        CloseHandle pi.hThread
        WinApi_CreateProcess = 0: Exit Function
    Else
        Debug.Print Err.LastDllError ' Not this branch
        CloseHandle pi.hThread
        WinApi_CreateProcess = pi.dwProcessId: Exit Function
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Tells you that the hThread field contains an invalid handle value.   It will when the VBA code runs in 64-bit mode, handles are LongPtr.  Happens to work by accident for hProcess because it is the first field in the structure.

Comment: @HansPassant How is that possible? I have an x64 computer but my Office is 32-bit, and the process I create is 32-bit, too. (In Task Manager I see `EXCEL.EXE *32` and `cmd.exe *32`. The path of the latter is `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe`.)

Comment: Okay, next bug is STARTUPINFO.lpReserved2, it is a pointer.  So Long or LongPtr, not Byte.   That one causes memory corruption when the OS writes too much data than fits the space in the variable, affecting an adjacent variable.  Which happens to be the pi variable in this code.  Not quite good enough to corrupt the hThread field, but the shoe fits.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected that one. However, it did not solve it. Since the OS only reads from si, it did not corrupt pi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After modify all pointer types to `LongPtr` instead of `Long`, I can use the sample to reproduce your problem with 64-bit Excel. You could also refer to the statement [here](https://github.com/itm4n/VBA-RunPE/blob/master/RunPE.vba)

```
Private Type SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    nLength              As Long
    lpSecurityDescriptor As LongPtr
    bInheritHandle       As Long
End Type

Private Type STARTUPINFO
    cb              As Long
    lpReserved      As String
    lpDesktop       As String
    lpTitle         As String
    dwX             As Long
    dwY             As Long
    dwXSize         As Long
    dwYSize         As Long
    dwXCountChars   As Long
    dwYCountChars   As Long
    dwFillAttribute As Long
    dwFlags         As Long
    wShowWindow     As Integer
    cbReserved2     As Integer
    lpReserved2     As LongPtr
    hStdInput       As LongPtr
    hStdOutput      As LongPtr
    hStdError       As LongPtr
End Type

Private Type PROCESS_INFORMATION
    hProcess    As LongPtr
    hThread     As LongPtr
    dwProcessId As Long
    dwThreadId  As Long
End Type
```

Then I get `true` result for `CreateProcess` and `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` error for `ResumeThread`, I found that `ResumeThread` parameter did not declare with `ByVal`(the same as `SuspendThread`). After add `ByVal`, the sample works for me.

```
Declare PtrSafe Function SuspendThread Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hThread As LongPtr) As Long

Declare PtrSafe Function ResumeThread Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hThread As LongPtr) As Long
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a bit hard to decipher your answer but the essence is that ResumeThread's and SuspendThread's parameter should be declared with ByVal. (Otherwise it's considered ByRef by VBA, so not its value but the address of the variable holding that value is given to WinAPI.)

Answer (score 1):

> LastDllError is 18 after calling CreateProcess although the return value is nonzero. What does this mean?

It means you are using `Err.LastDllError` incorrectly.  If `CreateProcess()` *succeeds* (returns non-zero), the value of `Err.LastDllError` is *indeterminate*, so just ignore it.  Its value will be meaningful only if `CreateProcess()` *fails* (returns zero).

> ResumeThread fails with ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE, and does not resume it. What is wrong here?

You are checking the return value of `ResumeThread()` incorrectly, so you are checking `Err.LastDllError` at the wrong time, again.

Per the [`ResumeThread()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-resumethread):

> If the function succeeds, the return value is the **thread's previous suspend count**.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is (DWORD) -1. **To get extended error information, call GetLastError.**

In this case, you are checking the return value of `ResumeThread()` against 0, but the process was created in a suspended state, so its main thread's suspend count would be 1, and so `ResumeThread()` should be returning 1 if the thread is successfully resumed, but you are treating that as a failure condition instead of a success condition.

You need to change this:

`If ResumeThread(pi.hThread) <> 0 Then`

To this:

`If ResumeThread(pi.hThread) = -1 Then`

And clean up your use of `Err.LastDllError`, eg:

```vb
Public Function WinApi_CreateProcess(strCommandLine As String, Optional strCurrentDirectory As String = vbNullString) As Long
    If strCurrentDirectory = vbNullString Then
        strCurrentDirectory = ThisWorkbook.Path
    End If
    Dim sap As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES: sap.nLength = Len(sap)
    Dim sat As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES: sat.nLength = Len(sat)
    Dim si As STARTUPINFO: si.cb = Len(si)
    Dim pi As PROCESS_INFORMATION
    Dim dwResult As Long: dwResult = CreateProcess(vbNullString, strCommandLine, sap, sat, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED, 0, strCurrentDirectory, si, pi)
    If dwResult = 0 Then
        Debug.Print Err.LastDllError
        WinApi_CreateProcess = 0: Exit Function
    End If
    CloseHandle pi.hProcess
    Dim dwSuspendCount As Long: dwSuspendCount = ResumeThread(pi.hThread)
    If dwSuspendCount = -1 Then
        Debug.Print Err.LastDllError
        CloseHandle pi.hThread
        WinApi_CreateProcess = 0: Exit Function
    End If
    CloseHandle pi.hThread
    WinApi_CreateProcess = pi.dwProcessId
End Function
```

But, you really don't need to create a process suspended and then resume it just to grab its process ID.  Get rid of `CREATE_SUSPENDED` and `ResumeThread()` altogether, you don't actually need them in this situation:

```vb
Public Function WinApi_CreateProcess(strCommandLine As String, Optional strCurrentDirectory As String = vbNullString) As Long
    If strCurrentDirectory = vbNullString Then
        strCurrentDirectory = ThisWorkbook.Path
    End If
    Dim sap As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES: sap.nLength = Len(sap)
    Dim sat As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES: sat.nLength = Len(sat)
    Dim si As STARTUPINFO: si.cb = Len(si)
    Dim pi As PROCESS_INFORMATION
    Dim dwResult As Long: dwResult = CreateProcess(vbNullString, strCommandLine, sap, sat, 0, 0, 0, strCurrentDirectory, si, pi)
    If dwResult = 0 Then
        Debug.Print Err.LastDllError
        WinApi_CreateProcess = 0: Exit Function
    End If
    CloseHandle pi.hThread
    CloseHandle pi.hProcess
    WinApi_CreateProcess = pi.dwProcessId
End Function
```

Comment: Where did you read that Err.LastDllError is indeterminate if the previous API call succeeded? My experience is that it is set back to 0 except for some cases where Windows wants to give some extended information

Comment: You are right about ResumeThread's return value, I've updated my code. However, this did not solve the issue. ResumeThread returns -1, and Err.LastDllError is 6.

Comment: I would like to create the process suspended.

Comment: @z32a7ul "*Where did you read that Err.LastDllError is indeterminate if the previous API call succeeded?*" - `Err.LastDllError` is just a wrapper for `GetLastError()`. The documentation for each API function tells you when `GetLastError()` is valid to use. In the case of most APIs, including `CreateProcess()`, the error code is valid only when a failure is reported by the API. Most APIs do not reset or update the error code on success, thus stale error codes can propagate through multiple APIs calls.

Comment: @z32a7ul "*ResumeThread returns -1, and Err.LastDllError is 6.*" - you are checking `Err.LastDllError` after calling `Debug.Print`, which can alter the error code from `ResumeThread()`. You have to read `Err.LastDllError` *immediately* after an error is reported, *before* making another system call.

Comment: @z32a7ul "*I would like to create the process suspended.*" - why, though? There is no point to doing that in this code. It is just wasted overhead.

Comment: Debug.Print is not a system call but part of VBA. And it is called after evaluating Err.LastDllError because you have to give the result of Err.LastDllError as an argument to Debug.Print. Anyway, I tried `Debug.Print dwErr`, then `Err.LastDllError`. But it prints 6, too.

Comment: @z32a7ul "*`Dim dwSuspendCount As Long: dwSuspendCount = ResumeThread(pi.hThread) Debug.Print dwSuspendCount`*" - calls `Debug.Print` before reading `Err.LastDllError`. And `Debug.Print` may be part of VBA, but internally it has to make its own system calls to print its output. Any of those system calls could reset the error code.

Comment: OK, I commented out that line and used the modification in my previous comment. No change, it is still 6.

Comment: @z32a7ul see the update I made to my answer